# How to launch VSCode to diff two files via protocol handler

Tags: visual-studio-code, url-scheme

I'm writing a UWP app and want to launch VSCode to diff two files, like you can do code.cmd --diff a.txt b.txt.
However because this is in a UWP app, I can't just start a process, instead I have to launch a protocol/Uri. 
I know there is a protocol handler to clone a repo, is there a protocol handler to diff two files?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alas, it's not a thing.  At least not now.  Alexander filed this feature request with the vscode team.  It's on the backlog, but not yet funded:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95184

Please bump it if you also need this capability.

Comment: If you can count on vscode having an extension installed, then you could write an extension that has a protocol handler in it.  (Though perhaps it would be about the same degree of difficulty as creating a pull request to vscode itself).